# LCP(linear complementary problem) implementation in Java

Tags: math, physics, linear-programming, physics-engine

I currently have an issue with a new project, because I need a solution for a LCP. I know there are
algorithms like Lemke etc. But each of them seems to be written in C++ or Python(using numpy).

I am not really able to implement an algorithm by myself, because I'm not completely familiar with all the math behind it.

So my question is if there is any LCP solver for Java which I can just use by calling something like

`SolveLCP(Matrix M, Vector q, Vector w, Vector z)`

for computing w and z from M and q ?

I found an algorithm at

https://www.geometrictools.com/GTE/Mathematics/LCPSolver.h

which seems to work pretty good, but unfortunately it's C++ and I failed to convert it into java(actually I use kotlin). My version has the correct results sometimes, but not every time compared with the C++ implementation.

I implemented it in kotlin, you can find it here:

https://github.com/mihisg/LCPSolver_Kotlin/tree/main

I would really appreciate it if someone could help finding the errors. I think I did something wrong with representing all those pointers, but in fact, it only works sometimes.

Comment: You could use a QP solver.

Comment: Good idea, thank you. But I can't find one either. Do you have a working one in java?

Comment: Google finds a ton of them. Both commercial, open-source and simple student projects.

Comment: Do you recommend a specific one? How can I formulate the LCP as a QP?

Comment: Good QP solvers are Cplex, Gurobi and Mosek. How to formulate an LCP as a QP is very standard and is even shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem. A little reading goes a long way.